# How to accept parameters and use them to create children objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a `Parent` object and would like to attach `Child` objects to it on create. How do you handle that in the controller?

In my form view, I would have these fields

- Name `:name`
- Children `parent[:child]

However, this causes errors when I include `:child[]` in the strong params.

I'm just a bit confused how Rails actually handles this and I could not find anything about this specifically online. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: This might help:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Parent
  has_many :childs, index_errors: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :childs, allow_destroy: true
end

class ParentsController
  def parents_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(parent_attributes_here_, 
      childs_attributes: [:id, :etc, :etc, :etc, :_destroy]
  end
end
```

`index_errors` will help to show errors to specific child model.
`:_destroy` will allow to destroy child

More information: [click](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try `cocoon` gem [here](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). It supports dynamic form for nested attributes. You can add many `Child` objects for your `parent` Object at the same time by using this gem. The `README` file includes guides for you to install and use it.

To understand what nested attributes, read Rails api [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)